# UPDATE by PRIMARY KEY query is too slow on big table

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, myisam

I have a MyISAM table (on a Mariadb) with 7 millions rows in it.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `y` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10152508 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1
```

When i do

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = 167880;
```

it takes around 0.272 sec

When i do

```
UPDATE mytable SET value = 1 WHERE id = 167880;
```

it takes randomly from 0.200 to 2.5 sec

I was thinking it's because my table have a lot of rows, but still, it shouldn't take that much time to update a row by it's primary key.

Since i did some researchs before posting, here are the checks i've already done :

- No duplicate indexes
- No others indexes than the primary key "id"
- No triggers
- Tried to switch to innoDB engine, it was worse (around 6 sec for an update)
- Tried to switch to aria engine, it's even worse
- Already did OPTIMIZE TABLE;
- Config is the default config of last version of Mariadb (fresh install)
- Made all theses check while the db was not used by anything else, so no heavy readings during the tests

Comment: Have you tried to drop and recreate the index?

Comment: Question, how are you connecting and executing the queries on your DB? Via ODBC or JDBC? Via a tool like DBeaver or in a program?

Comment: i'm using sqlyog to do the request directly, but the lag happens in PHP too, that's where i found the problem in the first place. I can't drop an auto incr primary key

Comment: @Owow That 2.5 sec is only in DB site or entire roundtrip from application?

Comment: What happens without `PAGE_CHECKSUM=1`?

Comment: What is the setting of `key_buffer_size` (when using MyISAM) or `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (when using InnoDB)?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have same issue and need your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is the data type you are using for id column. 
Using INT rather then BIGINT can make a significant reduction in disk space.
Read this article instead.
http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/bigint-v-int-is-there-a-big-deal-2008-07-18/
Hope it helps